# Display the 10 most used tags

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing an API using Codeigniter and in this API the users can tag
themself. I need to display the 10 most popular tags (most frequestly used tags). 
How can I do that?

**Update**

The tag table contains:

```
id, user_id, tag, created_at, updated_at
```

Comment: Provide some database-info and relevant code please.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where are you stuck? You'll have to give us a little more to go by, SO is no code factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonathan, depending on your setup the solution will be different, I'm going to suggest something a bit different than what your table structure looks like, you can use it if you want to.

```
.--------------.    .-------------.
|   userTags   |    |     tags    |
.--------------.    .-------------.
|  id          |    | id          |
|  user_id     |    | tagName     |
|  tag_id      |    .-------------.
.--------------.
```

To add a tag to your database:
    $data = array('tagName' => 'Mr. Niceguy');
    $this->db->insert('tags' => $data);

To add a tag to your user, you could use the following in a model

```
$data = array('user_id' => $uId, 'tag_id' => 1);
$this->db->insert('userTags', $data);
```

To recieve the most common used tags:

```
$this->db->select('tag_id');
$this->db->order('tag_id DESC');
$this->db->limit(10);
$this->db->join('tags', 'userTags.tag_id = tags.id');
$this->db->get('userTags');
```

**Edit:**

If you have to use your setup, do this instead:

```
$this->db->order_by('count(tag)', 'DESC');
$this->db->group_by('tag', 'DESC');
$tags = $this->db->get('userTags');

foreach($tags->result() as $tag) {
    var_dump($tag->tag);
}
```

Comment: Looking really interesting! Unfortunately I cannot change my DB schema. How can I alter your select code to work with my setup?

Comment: Thanks! But does that query really get the 10 most frequently used tags in the tags table?

Comment: There ya go. Does the latest edit work better? I tried it with some bogus data now and it seems to work for me.

Comment: That seems to work! Thanks. I am supposed to use: $this->db->select('tag');
   $this->db->limit(10);
   $this->db->distinct();
   $this->db->order_by('count(tag)', 'DESC');
   $this->db->group_by('tag', 'DESC');

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a combination of `order_by()` and `group_by()`. Group them by the tag name, and then order them by the count. I'm not sure if you can order by count in ActiveRecord though, so you might need to use raw SQL.